# (How) is it possible to bind/rebind a method to work with a delegate of a different signature?

Tags: c#, delegates, callback, signals-slots, currying

I'm a c++ developer having used signals & slots in c++ which to me seems to be analogous to delegates in c#. I've found myself at a loss in searching for the functionality provided by "bind", and feel I must be missing something.

I feel like that something like the following, which is possible in c++ should be possible in c# with delegates. Here is some psudo-code for what I would do in c++:

```
Slot<void> someCallback;

int foo(int i)
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << i << "\n";
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Slot<int> someCallback = bind( fun_ptr(foo), i );
    ++i; // added to show that late evaluation would be a non-trivial difference
    int result = someCallback();
    assert( result == 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find any reference to binding/rebinding with regards to c# delegates. Am I missing something? Is there some radically different way to do this in c#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C# we do something like this:

```
class Program {
    static Action Curry<T>(Action<T> action, T parameter) {
        return () => action(parameter);
    }

    static void Foo(int i) {
        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", i);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Action curried = Curry(Foo, 5);
        curried();
    }
}
```

Clearly the method `Foo` corresponds to your method `Foo`, just with the appropriate calls to `Console.WriteLine` instead of `std::cout`.

Next, we declare a method `Curry` that accepts an `Action<T>` and returns an `Action`. In general, an `Action<T>` is a delegate that accepts a single parameter of type `T` and returns `void`. In particular, `Foo` is an `Action<int>` because it accepts one parameter of type `int` and returns `void`. As for the return type of `Curry`, it is declared as an `Action`. An `Action` is a delegate the has no parameters and returns `void`.

The definition of `Curry` is rather interesting. We are defining an action using a lambda expression which is a very special form of an anonymous delegate. Effectively

```
() => action(parameter)
```

says that the `void` parameter is mapped to `action` evaluated at `parameter`.

Finally, in `Main` we are declaring an instance of `Action` named `curried` that is the result of applying `Curry` to `Foo` with the parameter `5`. This plays the same role as `bind(fun_ptr(foo), 5)` in your C++ example.

Lastly, we invoke the newly formed delegate `curried` via the syntax `curried()`. This is like `someCallback()` in your example.

The fancy term for this is [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

As a more interesting example, consider the following:

```
class Program {
    static Func<TArg, TResult> Curry<TArg, TResult>(
        Func<TArg, TArg, TResult> func,
        TArg arg1
    ) {
        return arg => func(arg1, arg);
    }

    static int Add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Func<int, int> addFive = Curry<int, int>(Add, 5);
        Console.WriteLine(addFive(7));
    }
}
```

Here we are declaring a method `Curry` that accepts a delegate (`Func<TArg, TArg, TResult>` that accepts two parameters of the same type `TArg` and returns a value of some other type `TResult` and a parameter of type `TArg` and returns a delegate that accepts a single parameter of type `TArg` and returns a value of type `TResult` (`Func<TArg, TResult>`).

Then, as a test we declare a method `Add` that accepts two parameters of type `int` and returns a parameter of type `int` (a `Func<int, int, int>`). Then in `Main` we instantiate a new delegate named `addFive` that acts like a method that adds five to its input parameter. Thus

```
Console.WriteLine(addFive(7));
```

prints `12` on the console.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I marked the other as the accepted answer because it is more concise, though it is missing some important details that yours included.

Comment: Sure. I just hope the extra color helps. :-)

Comment: Extremely useful answer, this.  Introduced a brilliant concept, currying, in an easy to understand manner.  Will definitely add this to my mental toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
class Example {
  static void foo(int i) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
  public static void Main() {
    Action someCallback = () => foo(5);
    someCallback();
  }
}
```

Or for something even closer to the C++ counter part

```
class Example {
  static void foo(int i) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
  static Action bind<T>(Action<T> action, T value) {
    return () => action(value);
  }
  public static void Main() {
    Action someCallback = bind(foo, 5);
    someCallback();
  }
}
```

Explanation.  What's happening here is that I am creating a new delegate by means of a lambda expression.  The lambda is the expression starting with `() =>`.  In this case it creates a delegate accepting no arguments and producing no value.  It is compatible with the type `Action`.

Comment: Woah. Interesting. What am I seeing here?

Comment: He's creating a new delegate using a lambda expression.  The delegate calls "foo(5)".  It's like making a new method on the fly to call foo(5) for you, then assigning it to the someCallback delegate.

Comment: `Action<T>` is a delegate provided by the framework. It's a function that takes one parameter (of type T) and returns nothing (void). He's assigning an anonymous function to that delegate (which he has named `someCallback`). The empty parens indicate that it takes no arguments, the expression after the `=>` is the body of the function.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Considering you provided this example, I don't suppose there is a generic bind available that automatically determines the return type?

Comment: @Catskul, no there is not in C#

Comment: After using this more extensively it appears that there is a very big caveat to the first example which makes it un-useable: delayed evaluation. If I do "Action someCallback = () => foo(i);" it takes the "i" at time of the callback rather than the time of assignment.

The second example however does work, but has the unfortunate side effect of needing a specific "bind" to be declared for each type of rebinding to be done.