# c# concurrent, overlapping callbacks

Tags: concurrency, callback

A short purely technical question:

If I have an uncertain amount of overlapping (time-wise) instances of the class below. Is it and how is it ensured, that the "this" in "call_back_when_done" belongs to the same "this" as it was in "Start"?

```
class MyClass{
 int ident = -1;
 bool ready = false;

 void Start(string url){
  ident = aStaticClass.DoSomethingAndForkThread(url, callback_when_done);
 }

 void call_back_when_done(){
  ready = true;
 }
}
```

e.g.:

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    new MyClass().Start(<aURL>);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can bind the function to "this" like described here using currying : [(How) is it possible to bind/rebind a method to work with a delegate of a different signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098322/how-is-it-possible-to-bind-rebind-a-method-to-work-with-a-delegate-of-a-differ)

I would prefer a lambda function for your example case like described here : [C# Lambdas and "this" variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103745/c-sharp-lambdas-and-this-variable-scope)

Lambda functions are bound to the scope of the "this" context where they are created. Members of your surrounding Class are automatically visible to the Lambda function. Using a Lambda function you'll get shorter code which can also better optimized by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It is guaranteed.
When you pass `callback_when_done` to `DoSomethingAndForkThread` in `Start`, you are not only passing the raw function pointer (like you would in C++ with `&MyClass::callback_when_done`, but some kind of tuple consisting of the method to call and the object on which the method should be called (`this`).

If you like it more explicit you can also write a closure manually:

```
void Start(string url) {
  var that = this; // that get's captured by the closure
  ident = aStaticClass.DoSomethingAndForkThread(url, () => that.callback_when_done());
}
```